# Getting click element, then running toggle class on another class within that element

Tags: jquery

I have this code of multiple bootstrap accordions, when someone clicks the card header I want the icon inside of that specific header to rotate while the accordion opens.

```
<div class="accordion" id="a">
   <div class="card">    
      <a class="card-header" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseone" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseone">
         <div class="font-weight-bold"><span class="plus"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>&nbsp;a</div>
      </a>

<div class="accordion" id="b">
   <div class="card">    
      <a class="card-header" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsetwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsetwo">
         <div class="font-weight-bold"><span class="plus"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>&nbsp;a</div>
      </a>
```

I have a class to just rotate

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I'm not sure how to just single out the clicked header and not apply the rotate on all of the headers.

For example, this would rotate all the icons in each header even if it wasn't the one clicked.

```
$(".card-header").click(function(e) {
    $(".plus").toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

I tried to use "this" to get the clicked element but then I couldn't figure out how to toggleclass rotate on the plus class. Toggleclass rotate on "this" would rotate the entire header and not just the icon which I want.

Maybe it's the way I have my html structured, i'm just not really familiar enough with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you register the click handler on a parent, `this` will do it:

```js
$(".card-header").click(function(e) {
    $(".plus", this).toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

Explanation: the second (optional) parameter of a jQuery selector syntax is the parent to look into and it defaults to `window` object. In your example, `this` is the DOM element with the class `"card-header"` you clicked in.

Thus `$(".plus", this)` will target all `.plus` elements found inside the clicked `.card-header`.

---

If, instead of being bound on a parent of `.plus`, the event was bound on a sibling, in the same common `.card-header` parent, you would have had to find the parent using `.closest()` and pass it as the second param of your selector. Example:

```html
<div class="card-header">
  <span class="plus">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="sibling-trigger">Test</span>
</div>
```

```js
$('.sibling-trigger').click(function(e){
  $('.plus', $(this).closest('.card-header')).toggleClass("rotate")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  use find() function:

```
$(this).find('.plus').toggleClass('rotate')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on to the right idea by using "this" to get the clicked element. Try taking a look at the [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method, which will allow you to find a child of the clicked element by css selector.

```
$(".card-header").click(function(e) {
    $(this).find(".plus")
           .toggleClass("rotate");
});
```